# How do I set the request accept header in nginx?

Tags: nginx, header

I need to set the request accept header for any URLs on certain path to `*/*`.

Here are the request accept headers being set currently:

```
GET /apiQuery/preview?view=location_csv&q=name:* HTTP/1.1
Host: www.blah.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

I want it to be:

```
GET /apiQuery/preview?view=location_csv&q=name:* HTTP/1.1
Host: www.blah.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
```

..for any URLs along the /apiQuery/ path.

Answer (score 3):

There is a module available for such a purpose called [HeaderMode](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule#more_set_input_headers).

```
more_set_input_headers 'Accept: */*';
```

**Downside**: This module is not distributed with Nginx. You will have to follow the installation guide to get this module integrated with your Nginx.

Alternatively, if you are using your Nginx as a proxy, you should use [proxy_set_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header) directive.

```
proxy_set_header Accept '*/*';
```